# How can I get independent JSON reference resolution between requests in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, json.net

I am attempting to add a custom IReferenceResolver implementation to an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC API application to reduce data in a JSON payload. However the reference resolutions are being shared between different requests.

It appears that a single instance of the ReferenceResolver is shared between requests. I want the references to be resolved independent of other requests, as different users of my won't have this shared reference context.

This is my `ConfigureServices` method in *Startup.cs*:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
                {
                    opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceResolverProvider = () => new ThingReferenceResolver();
                });
        }
```

This is my controller implementation along with my custom *IReferenceResolver*

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("")]
        public ActionResult<ThingsResponse> Get()
        {
            return new ThingsResponse
            {
                MainThing = new Thing { Id = "foo" },

                Things = new List<Thing>
                {
                    new Thing { Id = "foo" },
                    new Thing { Id = "bar" }
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public class ThingsResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty(IsReference = true)]
        public Thing MainThing { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(ItemIsReference = true)]
        public List<Thing> Things { get; set; }
    }

    public class Thing
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThingReferenceResolver : IReferenceResolver
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, Thing> _idReference = new Dictionary<string, Thing>();

        public void AddReference(object context, string reference, object value)
        {
            _idReference[reference] = (Thing)value;
        }

        public string GetReference(object context, object value)
        {
            var thing = (Thing)value;

            _idReference[thing.Id] = thing;

            return thing.Id.ToString();
        }

        public bool IsReferenced(object context, object value)
        {
            var thing = (Thing)value;

            return _idReference.ContainsKey(thing.Id);
        }

        public object ResolveReference(object context, string reference)
        {
            _idReference.TryGetValue(reference, out Thing thing);

            return thing;
        }
    }
```

On my first request I get the following response:

```
{
  "mainThing": {
    "$id": "foo",
    "id": "foo"
  },
  "things": [
    {
      "$ref": "foo"
    },
    {
      "$id": "bar",
      "id": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

On my second request I get the following response:

```
{
  "mainThing": {
    "$ref": "foo"
  },
  "things": [
    {
      "$ref": "foo"
    },
    {
      "$ref": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want my second request to look like my first request i.e. repeatable outputs.

Comment: Looking at the default implementation for local ids I can see use of the "context" (and type inspection), this might be an option but how do I "expunge" the results when the request is complete is my follow up question.

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/7217c484e9705b5e76585c8b7fcd489c8e021c23/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultReferenceResolver.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different results for the second request because MVC creates one serializer and caches it, which then caches references if you have reference tracking on like you do.

I think if you return a JsonResult with new serializer settings in each result then you won't have this problem:

[new JsonResult(yourData, new JsonSerializerSettings { ... })](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_JsonResult__ctor_System_Object_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_)

Answer (score 0):

One option I have come up with is to bypass configuring the JSON serializer that MVC provides and create my own for the request in question.

```cs
        [HttpGet("")]
        public ActionResult<ThingsResponse> Get()
        {
            var serializerSettings = JsonSerializerSettingsProvider.CreateSerializerSettings();

            serializerSettings.ReferenceResolverProvider = () => new ThingReferenceResolver();

            return new JsonResult(
                new ThingsResponse
                {
                    MainThing = new Thing { Id = "foo" },

                    Things = new List<Thing>
                    {
                        new Thing { Id = "foo" },
                        new Thing { Id = "bar" }
                    }
                },

                serializerSettings
            );
        }
```

In my specific scenario this is OK, because I do not have many endpoints that this would need to be configured for.

This means the following code from the example *Startup.cs* is **not needed** to solve my problem (as I define it per request)

```cs
                .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
                {
                    opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceResolverProvider = () => new ThingReferenceResolver();
                });
```

I think I will settle on this option for my circumstances, but would love to know if there are better ways to implement it.